# How to sign in the user after redirect through devise in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, multi-tenant, apartment-gem

I want to redirect a user first, and then sign the user in programmatically.

I've a multi-tanancy app, and when a user tries to sign in at the root domain, my app should not only redirect the user to his sub-domain, but also sign the user in.

So far, I'm trying to accomplish this through following code:

```
# In sessions#create ( Root )
redirect_to "http://#{account.subdomain}.localhost.com:3000/users/sign_in"
Apartment::Tenant.switch(account.subdomain)
sign_in(:user, account.owner) # Basically, owner is the user here.
```

When I run the code, it successfully redirects to the subdomain, but doesn't sign the user in.

I get the following error:

```
Completed 302 Found in 93ms (ActiveRecord: 39.7ms)
```

Also, it doesn't switch the `schema` when I do `Apartment::Tenant.switch(account.subdomain)`, because after running `Apartment::Tenant.switch(account.subdomain)` when I run `user = User.first`, the query that can be seen in logs is:

```
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "public"."users".* FROM "public"."users"   ORDER BY "public"."users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
```

Here, `public` corresponds to the `schema` of root domain, not the `schema` of sub-domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (only) solution after ton of search was to modify the following line in `config/initializers/session_store.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_examples_session', :domain => :all
```

Well, this isn't a perfect solution by any means, and it will do the job. What *exactly* does it do is actually maintain a session through all subdomains.

For example, if I log in at `bugs.example.com`, my session would also work at `attendance.example.com` and like these subdomains.

I also wrote a `before_action` that checks whether the subdomain the user is trying to login at - belongs to the user or not, if yes, I let the user log in and if not, I redirect the user to the subdomain that he belongs to, and if the user belongs to none, I redirect him to root url. Again, through one `session`, user would be able to login at every subdomain out there, so *this kind* of check is very important.